# JWT Auth in Vert.x 5

Tags: vert.x

I am using Vert.x 5.0.0 SNAPSHOT in a new project. We have code in previous Vert.x v4.4.3 projects to add JWT authorization to a router built from an OpenAPI spec:

```
RouterBuilder
   .create(this.vertx, OPENAPI_URL)
   .compose(routerBuilder -> {

      // AUTHENTICATION & AUTHORIZATION
      routerBuilder.securityHandler("bearerAuth", Config.jwt().getAuthHandler());

      //...
```

But in 5.0.0 there's only a `security` method that receives a String and returns a `Security` object. That security object then accepts a handler and returns a `RouterBuilder` again:

```
router
   .route("/v1/*")
   .subRouter(routerBuilder
      .security("bearerAuth")
      .httpHandler(Config.jwt().getAuthHandler())
      .createRouter()
   );
```

But when I run it, it throws an exception on the `.security("bearerAuth")` line:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 'securityScheme' cannot be null
```

I can't find documentation or examples on how to do this. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The OpenAPI spec needs to have the "bearerAuth" security scheme, and we were loading multiple files and it wasn't on every one of them.